# branch.io sharesheet questions

Tags: unity-game-engine, branch.io

Im using branch.io's sdk for unity, im having 2 questions im hoping someone could answer:

1: Is it any way to restrict the share sheet from sharing to certain apps? for example some apps that doesn't handle links well and in special the sms service.
The reason we do not want the ability to send by sms is that the app needs permission to access the phone book and thus the google play service will need an "privacy policy" link.

2: If its not then i would like to know if you guys could lead me in the right direction when writing a privacy policy because i do not have any legal education and do not know how to wright it. Is it sufficient to state that we are using your sdk? The demands are things like "you should see to it that the code is secure and encrypted" (Something like that) though i'm using your sdk and do not have a clue about how it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change the list of apps from the share sheet in Branch's Unity SDK. Although Branch does have an end point to exclude certain apps using the Android SDK.

You will need to export your Unity 3D project to Android Studio. Once you successfully export the project, you can use the Branch Android SDK endpoint to exclude any app by providing the Package name of the App.

This is the sample code to update your Share Sheet:

```
//define the share sheet style
ShareSheetStyle shareSheetStyle = new ShareSheetStyle(context, shareTitle, shareDescription)

.setCopyUrlStyle(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_send), "Copy this URl", "Link added to clipboard")
                    .setMoreOptionStyle(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search), "Show more")
                    .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.FACEBOOK)
                    .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.GMAIL)
                    .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.TWITTER)
                    .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.PINTEREST)
                    .setAsFullWidthStyle(true)
                    .setSharingTitle("Share With");

//to exclude whatsapp from the Share Sheet
shareSheetStyle.excludeFromShareSheet("com.whatsapp");

//to exclude android messages app from the Share Sheet
shareSheetStyle.excludeFromShareSheet("com.google.android.apps.messaging");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this out! Do you know if there is a similar option on ios?

Comment: Also, by disabling the native sms application, do you know if all sms services is disabled? Otherwise i assume that this does not entirely solve my problem with the privacy policy. Thanks!

Comment: @Struts what exactly do you mean by disabling all sms services. Using excludeFromShareSheet method, will only exclude the SMS application from the Sharesheet. It will not disable sending SMS from your device.

Comment: sorry if i explained poorly. What i want to know is if i can disable sms as an option overall in the share sheet, not just the native application. In that case you could still send from 3rd party sms applications.

Comment: @Struts sorry my answer was not clear earlier. The above will disable SMS option only from the share sheet on which you call the excludeFromShareSheet method. It will not disable sending SMS from your Native application. I hope this makes things clearer.